# Where can I find online interactive versions of classic experiments in psychology for the purposes of teaching?

Tags: internet, software, teaching-of-psychology

It's often useful and fun for students to experience well-known psychology experiments. Where can demo versions of famous psychology experiments be found online?

Some example paradigms that might be useful include:

- [Stroop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect)
- [IAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit-association_test)
- [N-back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-back)
- [Visual search, particularly pop-out effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_search)

Comment: If you want to really teach your class about cognition and group psychology there are a number of great experiments and fun activities you can do! Step 1. Rent out a former prison Step 2....

Answer (score 6):

*List presented alphabetically*

#### Cambridge Brain Sciences ([cambridgebrainsciences.com](http://www.cambridgebrainsciences.com))

Several "brain-training" type experiments including span tasks, mental rotation, and paired associate memory. Some tests require free registration on the site to complete. Data from the tests may be used for research purposes. Created by Adam Hampshire and Adrian Owen at University of Western Ontario.

#### Cognitive fun! ([cognitivefun.net](http://cognitivefun.net/))

Several n-back variants, basic response time tests (e.g. go/no-go), subitizing demo, flanker task, working memory span. Creator/source unclear.

#### Dual-Task ([dualtask.org](http://www.dualtask.org/))

Demonstrations of multi-tasking limitations. Experiments are Java applets. Site created by Hal Pashler at UCSD.

#### Go Cognitive ([gocognitive.net](http://gocognitive.net/demos))

Several cognitive experiments, including change blindness, visual search, implicit memory test, working memory capactiy, and selective attention. Experiments are Flash based. Site created by team at the University of Idaho.

#### Project Implicit (https://implicit.harvard.edu/implicit/takeatest.html)

Many variations on the implicit association test. Data is collected for research purposes. Created by team at Harvard University.

#### Simons Lab ([simonslab.com](http://www.simonslab.com/videos.html))

Several videos of classic selective attention / inattentional blindness studies, including the famous gorilla study. Students can do the gorilla study by watching a YouTube video. Videos of other experiments are more descriptive and less interactive. Site created by Daniel Simons at the University of Illinois.

#### Stroop demos

- http://ezyang.com/stroop/ - sequential presentation of words, press key to respond.
- https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/java/ready.html - simultaneous presentation of whole list. read aloud and hit button to indicate that reading is complete.
- http://www.math.unt.edu/~tam/selftests/stroopeffects.html - simultaneous presentation of whole list. read aloud and hit button to indicate that reading is complete.

#### Swarthmore Cognitive Psychology Demos (http://cogscidemos.swarthmore.edu/)

Three experiments: Visual search, Sternberg working memory task, & reverse Stroop. Implemented in JavaScript. Some parameters of trials can be adjusted. Data is nicely summarized at the end of the experiment, e.g. search functions are fit for the visual search task. Created at Swarthmore under the direction of Frank Durgin.

Answer (score 2):

[Inquisit](http://www.millisecond.com/) is a tool for running online psychological experiments.
It has [a huge task library](http://www.millisecond.com/download/library/).

A quick look says that they have:

- 6 different stroop tasks. E.g., http://www.millisecond.com/download/library/Stroop/FoodStroop/
- N-back  http://www.millisecond.com/download/library/NBack/
- Heaps of IAT examples: http://www.millisecond.com/download/library/IAT/AgeIAT/
- Becker's 2009 Visual search task: http://www.millisecond.com/download/library/VisualSearch/

The plug-in to run experiments is free and you can run the experiments online with just the plug-in.

If you have a desktop licence you can download and customise the scripts.
If you have a web licence you can post your modified scripts online and collect data.

Answer (score 1):

I've been developing [stato.de](http://stato.de), an online platform to run HTML5/Javascript experiments, recruit participants via email, Facebook, or Twitter, and collect and evaluate results in real time on any web browser.

Please see [Mental Rotation](http://statode-demo.herokuapp.com/mental-rotation) for a demo that works on phones, tablets, and desktops; it does not require signup.